# How can I display every element in this stack struct? (C)

Tags: c, struct, stack

I'm currently working on an assignment, and one of the questions involves a stack struct. I've found a suitable structure (a singly linked list structure), however I am unsure on how to display every element within the stack, as it makes use of multiple structs.

```
struct stack_entry {
    char *data;
    struct stack_entry *next;
};

struct stack_t { 
    struct stack_entry *head;
    size_t stack_size;
};

struct stack_t *newStack(void) { 
    struct stack_t *stack = malloc(sizeof *stack);
    if (stack) {
        stack->head = NULL;
        stack->stack_size = 1;
    }
    return stack;
}
```

So far, I've written this function - however it is of course non-functioning, as I'm stumped to say the least.

```
void display(struct stack_t *stack) { //displays all of the entries of the stack
    for (int i = 0; i < stack->stack_size; i++) {
        char *tmp = stack->head[i].data;
        printf("%s ", tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This `stack` looks an awful lot like a `linked list`

Comment: Unrelated: Why does a newly created `stack_t` have size `1` instead of `0`?

Comment: Part of the question states that the stack must contain at least one entry at all times, hence why the size was initialised as 1 instead of 0. I understand it may have seemed confusing at first glance hahaha

Comment: Indeed it does. :-) If it must contain at least one entry, you should probably also create that one entry?

Comment: That will be the next step; to add the "default" element of the stack. I feel like I shouldn't ask any more questions - as it'll take away from the learning aspect of the assignment, albeit the stressed it is causing me :)

Comment: Also, I appreciate the quick replies and your answer; it has helped me immensely :-)

Comment: @DarylRuggier Glad to hear it! You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` is a pointer to the first `struct stack_entry` and each `struct stack_entry` has a `next` pointer.

`char *tmp = stack->head[i].data;` tries to use `head` as an array which will cause undefined behavior.

You need to follow the pointers (links) until you reach a `NULL` pointer.

Example:

```
void display(struct stack_t *stack) { //displays all of the entries of the stack
    for(struct stack_entry *curr = stack->head; curr; curr = curr->next) {
        printf("%s ", curr->data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this (scans the list):

```
void display(struct stack_t *stack)
 { struct stack_entry *pEntry;  // current entry
   pEntry = stack->head;   
   while (pEntry != NULL)    
    { char *tmp = stack->head[i].data;
      printf("%s ", tmp);
      pEntry = pEntry->next;  // next element of list
    }
 }
```